# How to get rid of auto layout issue with labels and Stack view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I started a month ago learning iOS app development. I uses the "Beginning iOS 9 Programming with Swift" from Appcoda.

In chapter 9: Customize Table Views Using Prototype Cell - the tutorial was about to create a Table View using the Table View Controller object with custom prototype cells. There is a part where we added the custom labels for displaying the different information about a restaurant, like name, location and type. I added the labels to the IB (Interface Builder editor) and changes the names of it. Then select all of them and click the Stack button in the button layout the bottom corner-right. After I add the Stack to the three labels, I receive an error from Xcode in de Document Outline: Missing Constraints. (Figure 1.1) [image]

When I go through the tutorial and complete it with the specs the gave me, the errors are then as figure[image]

The book as include also the end project file of each chapter. I look at it and have compared it with my project file. Everything looks like exactly the same and I can't figure out why there is an issue with labels and Stack view. Does anyone know what I could properly got wrong?

Comment: click the traingle button at the bottom and select update frames option under all views.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, but I tried that already and the will not be updated.

Comment: IT should update. If not, click on the yello traingle on each of those warnings and choose update constraints option!

Comment: Still it does nothing.... :( So strange this issue. I've done the chapter more then once and still get the same error every time...

Comment: I tried in the example file of the book to position the stack view a little bit to the right and then I get the same issues as mine, don't know why I get the same issues than in the example file...